# How to show base64 string that is a qr code as image in terminal/cmd using python

Tags: python

I am trying to show a qrcode in terminal/cmd using python. I want to generate the qrcode using base64 that the url returns

Comment: And, how far are you and where is the problem you're facing? Please, as a new user here, take the [tour] and read [ask]. Your Q as it stands is not yet up to SO quality requirements.

Comment: I know I don't have any code to show. I can get the bas64 string thats it. But I am not able to find anything to print the qrcode in terminal

Comment: @alkanzwaans, the problem is that your question is more like a Google query. If you type "show qr code in terminal/cmd using python" in Google, you will get an answer with the first link. This forum was created to help, not as a replacement for a search engine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [this package](https://github.com/mnooner256/pyqrcode)

So,

```
url = pyqrcode.create(base64_string)
print(url.terminal())
```

will do the trick.

To read about other possible formats, please, follow [this link](https://github.com/mnooner256/pyqrcode#Rendering).